# How to generate a graph image from java heap dump

Tags: java, graph, out-of-memory, heap-dump

I wanna analyze a complex data structure that is raising an OutOfMemory error in a java environment. I already used the MemoryAnalyzer application (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) but since the data structure is complex, it's hard to understand the dominatior tree.

I believe that if I create a visual representation of the heap as a graph (with nodes and vertices) it will be easier to analyze. Does anyone know any tool to generate a graph image from a java heap dump (hprof file)?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://dr-brenschede.de/bheapsampler/
This generates a graph using graphviz.